# VS 2010 asp.net mvc v1 project upgrade

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

It seems I cannot upgrade my ASP.NET MVC v1 project to be able to open it in Visual Studio 2010. Anyone noticed that already?

"The project type is not supported by this installation."

??

edit...I actually want to upgrade it to ASP.NET MVC v2 if possible. If not, I will probably create a new ASP.NET MVC v2 project and copy the files there and then try to build.

Can't seem to get it why there are no replies yet, didn't anyone try this out yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To upgrade an existing ASP.NET MVC 1.0 application to version 2, follow these steps:**

Make a backup of the existing project.

Open the project file in a text editor (the file with the .csproj or .vbproj file extension) and find the ProjectTypeGuid element.

As the value of that element, **replace the GUID** {603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0} **with** {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}.

When you are done, the value of that element should be as follows:
{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}

For additional steps [read](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=46&p=1&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=7aba081a-19b9-44c4-a247-3882c8f749e3&u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2fC%2fC%2f0%2fCC0B980B-4D5A-4917-8F0A-610AB6CD5CB1%2fASP.NET-MVC-2-RC2-Release-Notes.doc&oRef=http%3a%2f%2fhaacked.com%2f) this.

Comment: Yeh... one of the things that you 'should' consider to read. :)